# Turning text into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-crawler, sitemap

I've successfully extracted my sitemap, and I would like to turn the urls into a list.  I can't quite figure out how to do that, separating the https from the dates modified.  Ideally I would also like to turn it into a dictionary, with the associated date stamp.  In the end, I plant to iterate over the list and create text files of the web pages, and save the date time stamp at the top of the text file.

I will settle for the next step of turning this into a list.  This is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import inscriptis
from inscriptis import get_text
sitemap = "https://grapaes.com/sitemap.xml"
i=0
url = sitemap
html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
text=get_text(html)
dicto = {text}
print(dicto)
for i in dicto:
        if i.startswith ("https"):
            print (i + '/n')
```

The output is basically a row with the date stamp, space, and the url.

Comment: Please share the output.

Comment: I can't really share the output here, since it's links.  But it's like this: 
https://grapaes.com/ 2020-01-12T09:19+00:00 https://grapaes.com/about-us-our-story/ 2020-01-12T12:13+00:00 https://grapaes.com/events/ 2019-12-05T13:17+00:00 https://grapaes.com/news/ 2019-12-19T14:43+00:00 https://grapaes.com/varieties/ 2019-12-05T13:31+00:00 https://grapaes.

Comment: @Unicorn_tech You should probably add that sample output into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the text around whitespaces first, then proceed like this:

```
text = text.split(' ')
dicto = {}
for i in range(0, len(text), 2):
    dicto[text[i+1]] = text[i]
```

gives a dictionary with timestamp as key and URL as value, as follows:

```
{
 '2020-01-12T09:19+00:00': 'https://grapaes.com/',
 '2020-01-12T12:13+00:00': 'https://grapaes.com/about-us-our-story/', 
  ...,
 '2019-12-05T12:59+00:00': 'https://grapaes.com/211-retilplast/',
 '2019-12-01T08:29+00:00': 'https://grapaes.com/fruit-logistica-berlin/'
}
```

I believe you can do further processing from here onward.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above: You could also use an XML Parser (standard module) to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
# Save your xml on disk
with open('sitemap.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

# Import XML-Parser
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Load xml and obtain the root node
tree = ET.parse('sitemap.xml')
root_node = tree.getroot()
```

From here you can access your xml's nodes just like every other list-like object:

```
print(root_node[1][0].text) # output: 'https://grapaes.com/about-us-our-story/'
print(root_node[1][1].text) # output: '2020-01-12T12:13+00:00'
```

Creating a dict from this is as easy as that:

```
dicto = dict()
for child in root_node:
    dicto.setdefault(child[0], child[1])
```